# Smack not getting presence

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am adding a user from spark to my client. In this case if I change the status on spark I am not receiving any presence packet. I have enabled debugging on and it shows no packet when status changed .

Whereas If i reverse the user login .
Ex: earlier A on Spark, B on my client.
Now : A on my client, B on spark.

In this case I receive the presence packets.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: When you reverse user login, do you have subcription request on Spark side ?

Comment: @Yul : No exactly understood what u are asking, but i have tried with subscription accept_all, also done it manually with sending subscribed packets.

Comment: @Yul : Thanks to you, your comment gave me a hint. See my answer

Comment: Happy to help :). Join this room for help [Chat app development](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/9351/chat-app-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kk so far, for anyone else I figured it out.

I made the subscription mode to manual in my client.

Then when receiving a subscribe request I replied with subscribed packet and a subscribe packet to the one send the subscribe packet to me.

Thanks to : Yul, his comment gave me a hint.